# Class mapping with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a plain database table (Named DBFoo):

```
| PropertyA | PropertyB| PropertyC | PropertyD | PropertyE |
```

PropertyA, PropertyB and PropertyC are part of the key.

And for this in my program I have following class structure:

```
public class Foo
{
   public virtual SubFoo SubFoo { get; set; }
   public virtual string PropertyC { get; set; }
   public virtual string PropertyD { get; set; }
   public virtual string PropertyE { get; set; }
}

public class SubFoo
{
   public virtual string PropertyA { get; set; }
   public virtual string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm trying to create the mapping file:

```
...
<class name="Foo" table="DBFoo">
   <composite-id>
      // here I Need to define the mapping for the SubFoo properties PropertyA and PropertyB
      <key-property name="PropertyC" column="PropertyC"/>
   </composite-id>
   <property name="PropertyD" column="PropertyD"/>
   <property name="PropertyE" column="PropertyE"/>
</class>
....
```

Anyone an idea how I can define the key-properties for the PropertyA and PropertyB?

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: have you tried key-many-to-one in order to map SubFoo itself?

Comment: @AliBaghdadi: thanks for your answer. yes first I tried with key-many-to-one. but then I need to create a second mapping file for SubFoo. I'm searching a way to define all in the same mapping

Answer (score 0):

Possibly is a bad idea, but you can try to generate a `FooIdentifier` class that decorates your `SubFoo` class to provide direct access to `PropertyA`, `PropertyB` and `PropertyC`.

```
public class FooIdentifier
{
    private SubFoo InnerSubFoo { get; set; }
    public FooIdentifier(SubFoo subFoo, string propertyC)
    {
        this.InnerSubFoo = subFoo
        this.PropertyC = propertyC;
    }   

    public virtual string PropertyA 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return SubFoo.PropertyA; 
        } 
        set 
        {
            SubFoo.PropertyA = value; 
        }
    }

    public virtual string PropertyB
    {
        get
        {
            return SubFoo.PropertyB; 
        }
        set 
        {
            SubFoo.PropertyB = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual string PropertyC { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the mapping file could be something like:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Foo" table="Foo" lazy="true" >
    <composite-id name="FooIdentifier" class="FooIdentifier">
      <key-property name="PropertyA" column="PropertyA" />
      <key-property name="PropertyB" column="PropertyB" />
      <key-property name="PropertyC" column="PropertyB" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="PropertyD" column="PropertyD" type="String" />
    <property name="PropertyE" column="PropertyE" type="String" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

As HuorSwords mentioned, you can define a composite key for your table, to do this, you have to create a composite key class which contains the properties AND overwrites the hashkey and equals methods...

Read [this blog](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2010/06/30/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.aspx) for further details of how exactly this should be implemented.

But I would strongly recommend not to use composite keys because there can be some issues in general. In addition it is recommended to have a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) more or less in each table and have secondary keys/foreign keys where needed.

This makes also the nhibernate mappings a lot easier!